# Xml data in yii widget CGridView

Tags: xml, yii, simplexml, cgridview

I have a question, is it possible to show xml information in a Yii frameworks widget CGridView? If it is, then how to do this using simplexml_load_file?
Thanks for your answers. Please don't comment and don't give negative feedback for this if you just don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I found solution by my self.
Convert xml data into an array and give that array for CGridView like a CArrayDataProvider.